# How to improve function for simplifying history command

Tags: bash, command-history, function

I came up with this snippet to simplify use of `history` and prevent flooding of the scroll buffer:

```
h() {
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        history | grep $1 | tail -n $(expr $(tput lines) - 1)
    else
        history | tail -n $(expr $(tput lines) - 1)
    fi
}
```

How can it be simplified to avoid repetition?

Answer (score 3):

Noting that `grep` with an empty pattern `''` matches every line, you could just always use it without testing:

```
h(){ 
    history | grep "$1" | tail -n $(($(tput lines)-1))
}
```

Comment: Of course. I didn't think of quoting the argument, which is sort of required anyway. And a more compact calculation of screen lines too. Very nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe in and out of conditional statements:

```
h() {
    history |
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        grep $1
    else
        cat
    fi |
    tail -n $(expr $(tput lines) - 1)
}
```

The `cat` is a no-op filter for symmetry.

Comment: I didn't know `if` fit within a pipe, but it makes absolute sense, as does the `cat`. Is it possible to lose `if` and friends in favor of some more compact syntax like `[ .. ] &&`?

Comment: @forthrin Suggestion for added feature: use `grep "$@"` instead of `grep $1`, this allows you to pass options to grep, e.g. type `h -i foo` and grep for foo case-insensitive.

Comment: Good thought, but putting the grep options inside the quotes fails, doesn't it?

Comment: @forthrin No, `"$@"` is special in the shell. When double quoted it expands to each positional parameter, with spaces in each parameter preserved. Try `set a "foo bar"; printf '<%s>\n' "$@"` to see this in action! This would not work with `"$*"`.

Comment: With `"$@"`, `h` without any arguments produces `usage: grep...`. So currently I'm using `"$1"` unless you have a fix.